# It it possible to make meta tag not a link to the image, but the image itself?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, api, meta

When user shares something on Facebook from my website, the meta image to be inserted into meta tag is generated (created via python lyb). The only way to show that image as meta image is to create api which will show that image by link inserted into meta tag?

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't know. I hope there is some way. Possibly Facebook would save it somehow, just to be sure whether it's impossible

Comment: By Facebook's definition the `og:image` should be a URL of the image.

Comment: And if you need individual images for different users sharing the same page you need individual page urls for every user since facebook caches the meta data after it's scraped.